# Expected Value of a CDF Theorem

Tags: probability

My professor wrote an equation out in class on the board that I wrote and didn't really look at until days later. The equality was this:

$P(Y<a)=E[P(Y<a|X))]$

What conditional expectation theorem is this? It's weird taking the expected value of a probability rather than a random variable even though I know that its logically makes sense once I stop to think about it.

What assumptions do I have to make to use this theorem?

Comment: How did you define $\mathbb{P}\{Y < a \mid X\}$ in class? This should be (and is) a random variable.

Comment: Oh that's right! It's an Fx measurable random variable. I mean.. I knew that. I was just testing you.....lol. I am kidding, I completely forgot. Thanks so much!

Comment: So I guess this formula links the unconditional CDF to the conditonal CDF.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mathbb{I}$ be indicator function. $\mathbb{P}(Y<a|X) = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}(Y<a)|X]$, the same applies for unconditional probability. So, your expression is equivalent to $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}(Y<a)] = \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}(Y<a)|X]\right]$.

Comment: Egor. Are you sure about your formula?? The one I wrote linked the unconditional CDF to the expected value of the conditional CDF. Your equation links the conditional CFD to the expected value of an indicator function. I think this is a different equation your referring too.

Comment: It is just a representation, any probability could be written as an expectation of indicator, and CDF is a probability. For more details, $\mathbb{P}(Y<a) = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}(Y<a)]$ by definition of an indicator, and the last equality is obtained using the law of iterated expectations (that is $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(A|B)) = \mathbb{E}(A)$).

Answer (score 0):

This makes use of the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

In general,

$$E[E[X|Y]] = E[X] \tag{*}$$

Here we have, noting that $P(Y < a | X) := E[1_{Y < a} | X]$,

$E[P(Y < a | X)] := E[E[1_{Y < a} | X]] \stackrel{(*)}{=} E[1_{Y < a}] = P(Y < a)$